# top -c command in linux to filter processes listed based on processname

Tags: linux, unix, process, top-command

```
top -c
```

Top lists all the processes, there are good options to filter the processes by username by using the option -u  but I am wondering if there is any easy way to filter the processes based on processname listed under COMMAND column of the top output.

For Example I would want like top -some option -substring of processname and top displays pids only having this substring in its command name

Answer (score 277, accepted):

Using pgrep to get pid's of matching command lines:

```
top -c -p $(pgrep -d',' -f string_to_match_in_cmd_line)
```

top `-p` expects a comma separated list of pids so we use `-d','` in pgrep. The `-f` flag in pgrep makes it match the command line instead of program name.

Comment: just remember that if new processes are spawned for 'string_to_match_in_cmd_line' they will not show up in top; you'd have to quit top and re-run this command

Comment: As eugenevd said, this will not work for new processes started after the top is called.
Is there any way to do so? I need to run several programs with the same prefix on its name, and I would love to see how many of them are running in a live way, not needing to execute a new top (or just a ps) every time.

Comment: @Jester, eugenevd, I had the same problem as you did. I made a new version at http://stackoverflow.com/a/27653841/681830, hope that helps.

Comment: I encountered `top: pid limit (20) exceeded` so I used this: `top -c -p $(pgrep -f string_to_match_in_cmd_line | head -20 | tr "\\n" "," | sed 's/,$//')`.

Comment: In case you on macOS `top -pid $(pgrep -d " -pid " -f -i string_to_match_in_cmd_line)`

Comment: @Vlad On macos 14 i am using  fish shell and it was failing on it but worked in bash and zsh.
any way to make it work on fish...
error : invalid -pid argument (not an integer): 627 -pid 769 -pid 24015 -pid 40256 -pid 40258

Comment: @Vlad Also can we enhance the command to accept multiple strings to match

Answer (score 164):

It can be done interactively

After running `top -c` , hit <kbd>o</kbd> and write a filter on a column, e.g. to show rows where COMMAND column contains the string foo, write `COMMAND=foo`

If you just want some basic output this might be enough:

```
top -bc |grep name_of_process
```

Comment: This gives me 'invalid option or syntax: -bc'

Comment: `top -bc -n 1 ` is more convenient, as it limits the number of iterations to 1.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's more acurate and works just with the options provided by 'top' command. And it does show new processes.

Comment: The processes keep on disappearing and reappearing with `top -c , hit o and write a filter on a column`.

Answer (score 129):

You can add filters to `top` while it is running. Just press the <kbd>o</kbd> key and then type in a filter expression.

For example, to monitor all processes containing the string "java", use the filter expression `COMMAND=java`.

You can add multiple filters by pressing <kbd>o</kbd> again.

You can filter by user with <kbd>u</kbd>. Clear all filters with <kbd>=</kbd>.

Comment: This is a better solution than the accepted answer (this solution posed 3 years later than the original). Unlike the original, this solution actually works on newly spawned processes as well. Very important if you're monitoring Apache processes that are created on-demand.

Comment: Indeed a better solution because it filters live. Accepted solution resolves process ids before running top. Resulting process is like `top -c -p 920,1345,1346` wich is fixed.

Comment: Using `o` as a filter does not exist in some (older) versions of top: `top: procps version 3.2.8` User filter exists, so that does work.

Comment: I think filters are and by default. How to make it or

Comment: any way to save my filter options, or invoke a filter like `CPU>0.0` from command line?

Comment: I get `error: invalid order: COMMAND=node` on macos . Yes i realize the Q has linux tag, but this helps let folks know that it works differently on mac

Comment: on macOS 14 pressing o does only sorting but does not filter.
i can only pass keyname i.e COMMAND which sorts only and passing COMMAND=iTerm2 completey fails..Anyway to make it work..top command on mac is broken or old version i guess..Cannot even install latest from brew...

Answer (score 13):

@perreal's command works great! If you forget, try in two steps...

example: filter top to display only application called yakuake:

```
$ pgrep yakuake
1755

$ top -p 1755
```

useful top interactive commands 
 'c' : toggle full path vs. command name
 'k' : kill by PID
 'F' : filter by... select with arrows... then press 's' to set the sort

the answer below is good too... I was looking for that today but couldn't find it. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

After looking for so many answers on StackOverflow, I haven't seen an answer to fit my needs.

That is, to make top command to keep refreshing with given keyword, and we don't have to CTRL+C / top again and again when new processes spawn.

Thus I make a new one...

Here goes the no-restart-needed version.

```
__keyword=name_of_process; (while :; do __arg=$(pgrep -d',' -f $__keyword); if [ -z "$__arg" ]; then top -u 65536 -n 1; else top -c -n 1 -p $__arg; fi; sleep 1; done;)
```

Modify the __keyword and it should works. (Ubuntu 2.6.38 tested)

2.14.2015 added:
The system workload part is missing with the code above.
For people who cares about the "load average" part:

```
__keyword=name_of_process; (while :; do __arg=$(pgrep -d',' -f $__keyword); if [ -z "$__arg" ]; then top -u 65536 -n 1; else top -c -n 1 -p $__arg; fi; uptime; sleep 1; done;)
```

Comment: this is missing an overview about the system's workload. add "uptime" before sleep, for short process lists, this is sufficient IMHO.

Comment: @Sevyls Thanks for pointing out! After other few attempts (that not work as good as) your version might be one of the best one. Answer modified.

Comment: Works great if I have one or more processes running that match but I get a "top: Invalid user" when all stop. It does recover when another process starts. I'm running on Raspbian FYI. Thanks.

Comment: @Vlad its not working on macOS 14 on bash (replaces -p with -pid still)
Pls Help. Also can you allow multiple keywords to be passed

Answer (score 6):

In `htop`, you can simply search with

```
/process-name
```

Comment: Unfortunately, htop is not always available and you may not have permission to add it.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a shell script with the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ 1 == 1 ]
do
    clear
    ps auxf |grep -ve "grep" |grep -E "MSG[^\ ]*" --color=auto
    sleep 5
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers fail here, when process list exceeds 20 processes. That is `top -p` option limit.
For those with older top that does not support filtering with `o` options, here is a scriptable example to get full screen/console outuput (summary information is missing from this output).

```
__keyword="YOUR_FILTER" ; ( FILL=""; for i in  $( seq 1 $(stty size|cut -f1 -d" ")); do FILL=$'\n'$FILL; done ;  while :; do HSIZE=$(( $(stty size|cut -f1 -d" ")  - 1 ));  (top -bcn1 | grep "$__keyword"; echo "$FILL" )|head -n$HSIZE; sleep 1;done )
```

Some explanations

```
__keyword = your grep filter keyword
HSIZE=console height
FILL=new lines to fill the screen if list is shorter than console height
top -bcn1 = batch, full commandline, repeat once
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone on a Mac, where top doesn't support the kind of filtering shown in other answers (and the pgrep args are slightly different)...  This function will launch top for the processes matching the pattern in the first arg (according to pgrep), and with any other args passed to top.

```
function topnamed() {
    name=$1
    shift
    top -pid $(pgrep -d ' -pid ' -fi "$name") $@
}
```

(The "i" in "-fi" makes it case-insensitive.)

Basic example showing any "python" processes:

```
topnamed python
```

Example with additional args for top:

```
topnamed python -o mem
```

It has the downside (mentioned in other answers) of only including the processes at launch time.

Comment: On macOS 12.6.1 delimiters are printed between each match. The usage of 99999999 is not needed. The `top -pid $(pgrep -d ' -pid ' -fi "$name") $@` working fine.

Comment: Thanks!  I see it working now on mine too.  I removed the workaround from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

what about this?

```
top -c -p <PID>
```

Comment: we are trying to filter by processname(or its substring) and when you restart your process you will get a new pid.

Answer (score 0):

This expect script will filter processes by name and show newly created ones. It is basically automate the user interaction with top by sending 'o' and 'COMMMAND=my_program' for you. similar to @nos Answer.

**file: topname.exp**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -- 

if {[llength $argv] < 1 } {
  send_user "Usage: topname process_name top_cmd_args \n"
  exit 1
}
set keyword [lindex $argv 0]

spawn top {*}[lrange $argv 1 end]


expect {

    -re .
     {
        send "o\r"
        expect "*add filter*"
        send "COMMAND=${keyword}\r"
        interact
    }
    
}
```

So you would use it like:

./topname.exp my_program

./topname.exp java `# this filters java processes`

Also it passed other flags that top accepts like -u
e.g.

./topname.exp java -u root `# this filters java processes by root user`

./topname.exp java -u root -d 1 `# this filters java processes by root user and delay top update by 1 second`